# Set RecyclerView start position when installing the app first time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, installation

Is there a way for me to set starting position for recyclerview, so when the user installs the app for the first time, and starts the app, the recyclerview will be shown at some position, and not from the start?

I have been using:

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(myPosition, 0)
```

But since the app is started for the first time, it is always default position shown in the recyclerview. The first param (myPosition) is set in the onBindViewHolder function.

I think this happens because recyclerview creates and destroys views while scrolling, so probably I would need to first iterate through the whole list, but not sure if the views will get destroyed in the end.

Comment: you should calculate myPosition by your own by finding position of desire item in underlaying data

Comment: what do you mean by "underlaying data"?

Comment: the one which is used to populate recyclerview

Comment: I did that, saved it in SharedPref, but it is not retrieved when I try to do sharedPref.getInt, instead I get the default value (0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you need some form of persistence to store if is the first time seen it.

So, first of all, you can't just scroll to the position because even if you pass the data immediately, the adapter doesn't immediately update. There is a delay.

You have to attach a `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` to the adapter and inside there do the scrolling.

```
 val observer = object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
         override fun onChanged() {
             if (isFirstTime) {
                 //scrollToPosition
                 //mark first time as no longer first time
             }
         }
     }
     adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer)
```

You might still need a delay, if so try with

```
viewlifeCycleOwner.lifeCycleScope.launch {
    delay(400)
    //scrollToPosition

}
```

You need to make your `firstTime` some form of persistence, so it remains across app-restart. I think `SharedPrefferences` should be enough.

Comment: First time I start the app, I am actually getting 0, aka default value when I retrieve the wanted position using shared preferences, like that part of the code where you set the wanted position to shared pref in OnBindViewHolder is not done yet

Comment: Change the default of the shared preferences? And that is not what I'm doing there. I'm checking a boolean in the shared preference to see if is the first time and then scrolling to the `myPosition`. Do you know `myPosition` before hand? That is what is deducible from your question.

Comment: I know it when I go through OnBindViewHolder in my recycler view adapter, that is where I set it in shared pref

Comment: Why? You can know that before passing through the adapter, the adapter receives a data set, so iterate the data ser and do the same calculation before passing it to the adapter.

Comment: Nop, I need to do some calculations with itemview in onBindViewHolder, and after getting the result, I put that result in SharedPref.

Answer (score 0):

You could save and load a variable to shared preferences, and once the user scrolls for the first time, that variable would change. (Just save a boolean - isFreshInstall, set to true as default and on scroll set it to false)

Then if the variable indicates it's the first time seeing the app just use a simple if to see ifyou should use myPosition or the position you want to show.

Comment: I did save it to sharedPref, but when I try to retrieve it, sharedPref.getInt() returns 0 instead of set position